# How to keep RichTextBox text selected while popup the ContextMenu?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

In my WPF project, I use a `RichTextBox`.

I write below code to popup its `ConextMenu` when user selects text of the `RichTextBox`. The function of the code is to convert the mouse up event to mouse right click event, which can popup `ContextMenu`.

```
var mouseUpEvent =
  new MouseButtonEventArgs(Mouse.PrimaryDevice,
      Environment.TickCount,
      MouseButton.Right)
  {
      RoutedEvent = Mouse.MouseUpEvent,
      Source = CurrentRTB,
  };

InputManager.Current.ProcessInput(mouseUpEvent);
```

It works. But it has a defect. Please check below pictures.

Picture 1: As you can see, when cursor is moved over a English word, like "tom", cursor is in the position between "t" and "m", then the whole word is selected. This is good case.

Picture 2: As you can see, when cursor is moved over a Chinese character, like "是", cursor is in the middle of the character，then the whole character is not selected. This is bad case.

Picture 3: As you can see, for Chinese character case, if we click right button of the mouse, then the selected characters become unselected.

That is to say, if the cursor is inside of the selected area, then right click can make popup `ContextMenu` while keeping the selected part. But if the cursor is outside of the selected area, then right click makes popup `ContextMenu` while losing the selected part.

My code above is to convert a mouse up event to mouse right click event(hence to popup `ContextMenu` via text selected), but has the same issue.
The solution I am looking for is:

(1) When right click mouse, can keep the selected part no matter the cursor is inside or outside of the selected area.

(2) When moving cursor over a Chinese character, can select the character in advance.

How to approach to either of them?

[image]
[image]
[image]